# How fetch specified column by rows number in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 5 column and a lot of rows. i want to fetch column number 3 for each rows that i select from my DB and store them in variables for compare together.

for example my data:

```
row 1 | column 1  column 2 column 3 

row 2 | column 1  column 2 column 3
```

then i want to store column 3  for each rows and store them in variables and then compare the variables :

```
variable 1 (row 1 , column 3) >=  or  =< variable 2 (row 2 , column 3)
```

Comment: What is the objective of this compare? Why you don't compare them with sql?

Comment: how can i compare them with sql?

Comment: As you said your DB has lots of rows and comparing rows in PHP is time consuming. Most of the time you can achieve your goal by writing query to select specific set of data by using control flow functions. Your objective is important for writing such query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$var = [];

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    $var[] = $row['column3'];
}
```

Then you can do anything with your variables array.